# How A53 driver to configure pl310?

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, arm64

I didn't find any information that any A53 platform is working with pl310 cache contronller.

I'm not sure using cache controller like pl310 is still a typical way for A53 aarch64 platform.

If I have to use pl310 in my A53, how can I write driver for it under Linux? Lots of pl310 registers are "secure" write only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no Linux kernel expert, but I would say there already is a `"arm,pl310-cache"` compatible driver for the PL310 and friends in Linux, [arch/arm/mm/cache-l2x0.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.5/source/arch/arm/mm/cache-l2x0.c).

Update: this is a five years old whitepaper, but its [does mention](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/developer/products/system-design-tools/cycle-models/Resources/Whitepapers/Cortex%20A53%20System%20Optimization.pdf?revision=67faf844-eca8-4bde-ad40-855680462ea7) the pl310.

But the kernel documentation for the l2c2x0 driver has the following note:

```
Note 1: The description in this document doesn't apply to integrated L2
    cache controllers as found in e.g. Cortex-A15/A7/A57/A53. These
    integrated L2 controllers are assumed to be all preconfigured by
    early secure boot code. Thus no need to deal with their configuration
in the kernel at all.
```

Comment: this is for arm32 mode, on aarch64, some of registers only write able by secure world, but kernel usually runs in non-secure el1

Comment: I see, you wanted to know how to write a new one suited to your needs. In this case, may be you could use the existing one as a basis, and replace portions of code by calls to functionally equivalent SMC services calls, the way `drivers/phy/marvell/phy-mvebu-a3700-comphy.c` and `drivers/mailbox/zynqmp-ipi-mailbox.c` are doing. In this case, you would have to create new SMC service calls and add them to your ARM Trusted Firmware bl31/secure monitor.

Comment: I was wondering, do you have a Cortex-A53 target with a PL310 cache controller in your hands right now, or do you want to know if such an hypothetical platform would work according to your requirements ?

Comment: I will look into the example code using SMC, thanks a lot

Comment: According to the note, you should not need configuring the pl310 in the kernel, thus implementing SMC calls and using them from the kernel should not be needed either.

Comment: Hi, the whitepaper link is broken. Can you please fix it?

Comment: @nachiketkulk: Not really, sorry,  I had found it on Arm WEB site.